# Is there a way to validate IPv4 address range in Aurelia and mask value using aurelia-mask?

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to validate and IPv4 range in Aurelia as well as mask the value using aurelia-mask which you can find here https://github.com/ariovistus/aurelia-mask.

I have two inputs(StartIp and EndIP) for IPv4 IP address which should be validated against the following scenarios.

1. StartIP can't be greater than EndIP;
2. EndIP can't be smaller than StartIP;
3. Both should be valid IPv4 addresses;

As well I want to display those values as masked but aurelia-mask support only number masking not IPv4 addresses.

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="startIp">Start Ip</label>
          <input masked="value.bind:StartIp & validateOnChange; mask: 999.999.999.999;" class="form-control" id="startIp"
            disabled.bind="disabled()">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="endIp">End Ip</label>
          <input masked="value.bind:EndIp & validateOnChange; mask: 999.999.999.999;" class="form-control" disabled.bind="disabled()">
        </div>
      </div>
```